# Remove older windows network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, tethering

I am using USB tethering from android smartphone for internet connection in my PC and every time I connect it with PC it establishes new connections and now count reached at 102.

Is there any method to establish a permanent connection and removing older connection?

Thank you

Comment: I have found similar question but the answer is not satisfactory as it as some registry configuration : [Why can't Win7 remember my tether? New Connection Setup every time](http://superuser.com/questions/464227/why-cant-win7-remember-my-tether-new-connection-setup-every-time)

Answer (score 0):

I have an older tethered phone with the same issue - - these all work for me - - the focus of these tricks is to get the connection to keep a specified name for that tethered adapter.

Three workarounds (all irritating):

Network and Sharing Center >> 
   Change Adapter Settings >> 
       Properties (right-mouse-click on your adapter), then choose:

(1) Copy all of your connection details into a new hardware profile, making sure to set the new properties of the tethered adapter have a static IP address and other details you normally see after you have connected.

(2) If you can somehow get another tethered adapter and phone (even just temporarily), connect more than one of the exact same tether to the unit.  Connect both, then disable the adapter of the unit with the higher id.  Set up an alternate property on the first adapter.

(3) Set up a bridged network connection to one of the other adapters (except not a VPN connection).

I know it is not perfect, but other solutions require registry manipulation, which is you doing Microsoft and / or the hardware developer's job for them IMHO...
   Hope that helps, 
                ClaireW